# Twig sort array of objects by field

Tags: twig

I have entity with fields:

**User**

- name
- lastname
- age

and few more. Im sending to Twig array with objects user.

In twig display users in table:

```
 {% for user in users %}
     <td>{{ user.name }}<td> <td>{{ user.lastname}}<td> <td>{{ user.age}}<td>
 {% endfor %}
```

How can I sort users via name or lastname etc. in Twig. I want to create sortable table.

Comment: I don't think it's a task for twig. You should sort them in your controller (or the model, that may be even better) and pass the already-ordered list to twig.

Comment: Yes. This isn't really for the template. 1. You said you have two entity fields, which suggests you got the list from the database. Set your sorting in the query when you make the request.

Answer (score 30):

Starting with Twig 2.12 (released on October 5, 2019) you can use the `sort` filter with an arrow function in the `arrow` argument.

For example, to order by name:

```
{% for user in users|sort((a, b) => a.name <=> b.name) %}
    <td>{{ user.name }}</td> <td>{{ user.lastname}}</td> <td>{{ user.age}}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Twig docs: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/sort.html

Comment: Awesome, most elegant and simplest solution, works like a charm for me. Should be the accepted answer I think. For those who wonders <=> is the [spaceship operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.spaceship-op).

Comment: Do you know how to perform multi field sorting?  e.g. sort age desc and then name asc?

Comment: @biko `|sort((a, b) => a.age <=> b.age ?: a.name <=> b.name)` this should work. If you want to switch from asc to desc (or the other way) just switch a with b.

Comment: I'd wish I saw this before reading through all the others.

Comment: Works also in Octobercms!

Comment: For case insensitive sorting use the `lower` filter: `sort( (a, b) => a.name | lower <=> b.name | lower )`

Comment: When I use that, I have a syntax error on the spaceship operator : `Unexpected token "operator" of value ">".` I want to sort an array ASC with an integer property.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, You can add custom filter:

```
{% for user in users|usort %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

and then add Extension/new filter to Twig:

`new \Twig_SimpleFilter('usort', array($this, 'usortFilter'))`

```
public function usortFilter($item){
    usort($item, function ($item1, $item2) {
        if ($item1['orderNo'] == $item2['orderNo']) return 0;
        return $item1['orderNo'] < $item2['orderNo'] ? -1 : 1;
    });

    return $item;
}
```

Comment: i know this is an old Q/A, but in case someone ever wanders here, I created this custom filter a while ago : https://gist.github.com/DarkMukke/f3b0243f957a9f820999e3b18766467b

Comment: I get `Illegal string offset 'orderNo'` when I use this code.

Comment: @JeremyJohn, beacause you dont have `orderNo` in you array.

Comment: how do you add filter to twig?

Answer (score 6):

Sorting in reverse order:

```
{% for user in users|sort|reverse %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

sort and revers are combinable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Timber for Wordpress which still uses Twig 1+, so I couldn't use the arrow argument. I just created a filter like this using PHP’s usort function:

```php
// sort an array of objects by parameter
$twig->addFilter( new Twig_SimpleFilter( 'sort_by_key', 
    function ( $array, $key, $order = 'asc', $type = 'string' ) {
        usort( $array, function($a, $b) use ($key, $order, $type) {
        $a = $a[$key]; $b = $b[$key];
        if( $type === 'date' ) {
            $a = strtotime( $a );
            $b = strtotime( $b );
        }
        if( $a == $b ) {
            return 0;
        }
        switch( $order ) {
            case 'desc' : case  'DESC' :
                return $a < $b ?  1 : -1;
                break;
            default :
                return $a < $b ?  -1 : 1;
        }
        }  );
        return $array;
    }));
```

And then in my twig template:

```twig
    {% set array = myArrayOfObjects | sort_by_key('date', 'desc', 'date') %}
```

Works well with the Advanced Custom Fields repeater field.

Comment: This works fine with arrays. but will not work with Timber\PostQuery Object (`posts`) or CallbackFilterIterator (`posts|filter(...)`).

Comment: Sure, because it’s meant to work on an a keyed array, not an object (stdClass). For posts, you’d probably just use the PostQuery to sort them anyway. Or you could write a filter using the PHP get_object_vars function to convert to an array first.

Answer (score 1):

With new version twig you can sort by colonne

```
{% set fruits = [
{ name: 'Apples', quantity: 5 },
{ name: 'Oranges', quantity: 2 },
{ name: 'Grapes', quantity: 4 },] %}
{% for fruit in fruits|sort((a, b) => a.quantity <=> b.quantity)|column('name') %}
    {{ fruit }}
{% endfor %}
```

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/sort.html

Answer (score 0):

You must do this in your model using an "Order by" clause. However, if you want to have a table that can be sorted dynamically, you should watch about the jQuery tablesorter plugin (or equivalent if you do not want to use jQuery).

http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Before Twig 2.12 It was not possible out of the box to order by specific field. Update your twig, or you could write a custom twig extension which does what you need. See @cgaldiolo and @unbreak answers.

Answer (score 0):

For those working with [Collections in Grav](https://learn.getgrav.org/16/content/collections#accessing-collections-in-twig), you can simply do this:

```
{% for user in users.order("name", "asc") %}
     ...
{% endfor %}
```

Of course, `name` can be any property of the given object and `asc` can alternatively be `desc`.

This also works with dot-concatenated properties:

```
{% for child in page.children.order("page.headers.foo.bar", "desc") %}
```