# Sort array by email in Twig

Tags: sorting, twig

I have an array of users that I'm looping trough to display on a page.I want to sort the users by their email, but I cant figure out how to do this, I've read trough som of the other questions, but cant get them to work. Any ideas?

```
{% for group in person.teachers %}
    {{person.img}}
    {{person.name}}
    {{person.description}}
    {{person.email}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twig sort array of objects by field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25194470/twig-sort-array-of-objects-by-field)

Comment: Probably a better idea to sort in your controller so that group is already sorted.

Comment: Hi Alvin, I use the Timber Starter Theme, and found the content function in the post.php file and I'm trying to sort the content.

usort($content.get_field('person'), function ($item1, $item2) {
  return $item1['email'] <=> $item2['email'];
});

But I think the $content.get_field('person') is wrong

I'm running php 7.1