# How to show list of names under the title on Twig

Tags: php, twig, symfony4

I am trying to show the list of users that are members of a same groups with a title. 
I have several groups with different titles.
All that information I have collected in 'evals' => $evals parameter that I pass to TWIG.

When I dump my $evals I can see the following:

```
RolesController.php on line 168:
array:774 [▼
0 => array:2 [▼

"title" => "2018"
"name" => "Jack"
]
1 => array:2 [▼

"title" => "2018"
"name" => "Peter"
]
2 => array:2 [▼

"title" => "2018"
"name" => "Mary"

3 => array:2 [▼

"title" => "School"
"name" => "Fred"
]
4 => array:2 [▼

"title" => "School"
"name" => "Neal"
```

========================================
What I would like to see in Twig is:

2018

Jack
Peter
Mary

School

Fred
Neal

========================================
What I have already (using the code below) is

2018

SOMETHING

School

SOMETHING

========================================

```
<Table>
{% set newArray = [] %}
{% for row in evals %}
    {% if row.title not in newArray %}
        <tr >
            <th> {{ row.title | upper }}</th>

        </tr>
        <td align="center">


    SOMETHING


        </td>





        {% set newArray = newArray|merge([row.title]) %}

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Can anyone help me with how can I get names from my evals and put it into order under a title, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ordering an array of object with twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54325567/ordering-an-array-of-object-with-twig)

Comment: There's a fiddle to help you : https://twigfiddle.com/vpiwus. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54325567/ordering-an-array-of-object-with-twig

Comment: Why don't you do that logic in your controller ? Best than having to do that in your view