# Reorder array of months

Tags: twig

I would like to sort an array of months in the reverse/regular month's order.

At the moment I have the following array

`["August", "July", "June", "May", "April", "March", "February", "January", "September"]`

I would like to be like

`["September", "August", "July", "June", "May", "April", "March", "February", "January"]`

I used the [sort](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/sort.html) filter but it sorts in ascending or descending order only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Twig sort array of objects by field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25194470/twig-sort-array-of-objects-by-field)

Comment: @DarkBee I tried with that but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please add what you've tried to the question

Comment: @DarkBee sorry but I am not able to start with those answers. There is nothing to show. Please help me if you think those answers work.